# Preview many windows at once @ Win XP

Tags: windows-xp, citrix

At work, I have to use Citrix to connect to remote desktops "somewhere". Currently I'm using 4 Citrix connections (4 windows) and I have 2 screens.

The thing is have to monitor progress on all 4 Citrix windows, and switching them regular way (clicking task bar or Alt-Tabbing) seems quite ineffective.

I would love to be able to re-size them (shrink) to be able to put all 4 of them on 1 screen side-by-side (kind of grid view). But they have to be "live" - need to see the progress on them. And I don't mean resizing regular way, I need to see the whole desktop, just smaller.

Alternatively, maybe some kind of Alt-Tab replacement (with live preview) would work.

I am limited to Win XP only.

I hope we'll find the solution, what are your ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [mRemote](http://www.mremote.org/wiki/), it seems to allow Citrix connections, although I dont have Citrix library installed to test.

Then open up 4 instances and resize them to suit your screen.

Comment: Haven't know it's possible to access Citrix without using Citrix itself [kind of ;)]. Thanks for pointing that out. Is there any faq explaining how to use mRemote with Citrix?

Comment: Ill be honest, I have never had anything to do with Citrix I only see it mentioned that it fails (because i dont have a library installed) when I load up my version of mRemote.

Remote desktop / ssh etc is just a matter of inputting the ip and hitting connect.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly something with an MacOS Exposé like feature would help you.

You can try "Switcher", found [here](http://insentient.net/)

You can also look for "Exposé for Windows" search results either on SuperUser (like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/30491/expose-for-windows) or on Google) if this functionality is what you look for.

Comment: Yup, Expose would work :) Switcher, unfortunately, wont work, as it requires Vista or higher. I will take a look at other clones.

Comment: Ah sorry, apparently I only tried that on 7 and Vista then.